# Check for existence before submitting data to the MySql database

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a PHP code that submits data to the database, but I want to restrict the data if it already exists. I have tried the below code but always inserts data without checking for existence.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

  $phone = $_POST['phone'];

  $checkDataSql = "SELECT phone FROM lead WHERE phone=$phone" ;
  $run = $conn->query($checkDataSql);

  if ($run->num_rows > 0) {
      header("location:add_lead.php?error=unsuccess");
      }
  else{
      $phone = $_POST['phone'];
   }

  $name = $_POST['name'];
  $email = $_POST['email'];
  $gender = $_POST['gender'];
  $treatment = intval($_POST['treatment']);
  $date = date('Y-m-d');
  $source = intval($_POST['source']);
  $staff = intval($_POST['staff_id']);


$insertLead = "INSERT INTO lead 
      (`id`, `name`, `phone`, `email`, `gender_id`, `treatment_id`, `date`, `source_id`, `remark`, `staff_id`)
      VALUES (NULL, '$name', '$phone', '$email', '$gender', '$treatment', '$date', '$source', '', '$staff')";



if ($conn->query($insertLead) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
    header("location:add_lead.php?submitted=successfully");
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $insertLead . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}


}
```

Comment: what's not working here, your code looks ok. If it's just a matter of exiting the headers, then see the answer below. If that doesn't solve then I have my own ideas as to why your code could fail.

Comment: btw, what is the value of `$phone`? and where's the html form for this?

Comment: Yes, Fred-ii, the code was ok, the only issue was with the `header()`, using this below solution it worked, thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the header to redirect doesn't do the redirect immediately, so you need to add something like

`exit;`

After both of the `header()` calls to stop execution at that point.

Additionally, look into SQL injection right now, you're code is totally insecure and you'll be hacked before you know it with it as is.

Comment: Thanks Luke, I was breaking my head from morning because of the simple thing. And also as you suggested, I will make it secure.

Comment: Cool. You'll also need to swap around the `echo "New record created successfully";` line with the `header()` as all headers must be set before the output (as the output will have already caused the headers to be sent). Although no-one will see that in a normal situation as their browser will have redirected them.